# Not enough top margin in PDF reports of qweb template of external_layout_standard in Odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I am using Odoo 12 and I need to print pdf reports using qweb templates of company templates. I use `<t t-call="web.external_layout">` to call the company's default header and footer then add my own content for report body, but there is not enough top margin between the header and body content which I add to the report. I tried to solve it by adding `padding-top` to what I add and it affects just the first page of report but on other pages. Also, I tried to create and register my own custom paper format for this template using below code:

```
<report id="action_admission_form_report" string="Admission Form" model="hms.surgery" report_type="qweb-pdf" file="nl_hms_hospitalization.report_nl_admission_form" name="nl_hms_hospitalization.report_nl_admission_form" />


    <record id="paperformat_admission_form" model="report.paperformat">
        <field name="name">Admission Form</field>
        <field name="default" eval="True" />
        <field name="format">A4</field>
        <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
        <field name="margin_top">50</field>
        <field name="header_line" eval="False" />
        <field name="header_spacing">5</field>
        <field name="dpi">90</field>
    </record>

    <record id="nl_hms_hospitalization.action_admission_form_report" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
        <field name="paperformat_id" ref="nl_hms_hospitalization.paperformat_admission_form"/>
    </record>
```

But it seems that I can not do it (maybe due to not support of Odoo 12 for it). Please guide me with how can I add margin or padding between the default header of the external_layout_standard template of the company for all pages?

Comment: You mean to put a blank space, between header and the body of page in every page? could you post a picture of what the output should be?

Comment: Yes, by using padding-top I added some padding for first page of the report on the mentioned template, but it doesn't work for the rest of the pages.

Comment: Even if you make the top margin bigger the blank space will be on the top of the page not under the header, I think you need header bottom margin, and new paper format with large marge header but could you post a picture of the desired output

Comment: I tried to add my own paper format, but I think the way it was being done in Odoo 10 is not supported now for version 12. Actually I have no idea how to register paper format with my report in Odoo 12.

Comment: `<record id="report_id" model="ir.actions.report">`  the model is `ir.actions.report` not `ir.actions.report.xml`.

Comment: The problem here when you make the to margin larger the header is center you will see some extra space between to top of the page and the header, and extra space between the header and the content . if this okay then just define a new paper format for your report

Comment: Yes, you're right.